# sending two values to sql query in loop

Tags: php

This is the screenshot of table `order_items`
[image: This is the screenshot of table <code>order_items</code>]

Code

```
<?php
$aa = "SELECT * FROM `order_items` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$result= $mysqli->query($aa);

while($ord = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $bb = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` = ".$ord['product_id'];
    $results = $mysqli->query($bb);
    $obs = $results->fetch_assoc()
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $obs['name'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $obs['code'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $ord['quantity'];?>
    </td>
<?php }?>
```

There are two tables `order_items` and `products`.
In the table order_items there are different `product_id` to the same `order_id`.

The above code is working properly if there is one `product_id` related to one `order_item` but if there are more than one `product_id` related to one `order_item` then this code is not working.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? i don't catch it... what do you need?

Comment: I was just editing your post and shouldnt there be a `</tr>` before the php closing bracket?

Comment: "...then this code is not working" So what happens?

Comment: The issue is that in the second query $bb if the value is more than one and the loop is not working. But if there is only one value then i am getting the desired result. And please ignore the html part it is just a rogh idea..

Comment: @Mihailo there is no result..

Comment: Shouldn't the first query be `WHERE order_id = $id`?

Comment: You should use a `JOIN`, instead of separate queries.

Comment: Please show some sample table contents and the desired result from it.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: would you please post all the fields and sample value of table order_items. Because you are getting order_items record by using its id

Comment: put `$obs = $results->fetch_assoc()` to while loop even if only one record and see the effect. and also the echo statment inside that second while loop

Comment: *"if there are more than one `product_id` related to one `order_item` then this code is not working"*: that does not make sense, since the `order_item` has the `product_id` field, so it defines *one* product, not more than one.

Comment: @ShaileshSingh screenshot of table attached.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `order_items` WHERE `id` = '$id'` this first statement will always return only one record so there no need of while loop. you are comparing your primary key to the $id.

Comment: I think you are trying to get SELECT * FROM `order_items` WHERE `order_id` = '$id'

Comment: @Barmar thanks it worked...
just a small error..

Comment: yes @ShaileshSingh .. got it..
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the two queries into one. And when querying the `order_items` table, you should be testing the `order_id` column to get all the products in an order.

You should also use a prepared query to avoid SQL-injection.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.name, p.code, oi.quantity
        FROM order_items AS oi
        JOIN products AS p ON p.id = oi.product_id
        WHERE oi.order_id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name, $code, $quantity);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $name;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $code;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $quantity;?>
    </td>
<?php }?>
```